# What happens if I pass a temporary reference and store it as a class member?

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino, pass-by-reference, arduino-c++

I have a class that stores a reference to some kind of application state, which it then mutates during operation:

```
class Mutator {
    private:
        State& _state;

    public:
        Mutator(State& state);
        ...
};

Mutator::Mutator(State& state) : _state(state) {

}
...
```

Normally I would create and pass the `state` like this:

```
State state;
Mutator mutator(state);
```

What would happen to the state reference in my Mutator class, if I initialize the Mutator like this:

```
Mutator mutator(State());
```

I assume, since the state reference is temporary, the `Mutator._state` member will point to a memory location which may or may not contain the state value which leads to unpredictable behaviour. Is this correct?

Comment: This is a general C++ programming question and has nothing to do with Arduino. It really belongs into StackOverflow.

Comment: @Kwasmich I still answered and asked the question to be moved to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a reference, then the variable needs to be initialized (as not being NULL) in the constructor. This is safer, since you are assured the reference is really pointing to an existing object.

About

```
Mutator mutator(State());
```

This does not make much sense, unless the State object is used only as input for the Mutator constructor; however if it changes the newly created State variable, when the constructor returns and mutator is created, the State() instance is deleted.

Also (see note of NathanOliver below), it is not legal C++ code and not portable.

**Update**

Test application:

```
class State {
    public: State() {}
};

class Mutator {
    private:  State& _state;
    public:   Mutator(State& state) : _state(state)  { }
};

void setup() {
    Mutator mutator(State());
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiler and links correctly on an Arduino compiler (1.8.9):

```
Sketch uses 260 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 0 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8192 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
```

Comment: `Mutator mutator(State());` won't compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver On an Arduino Uno compiler it compiles and links (I will add it to my answer)

Comment: @NathanOliver, it is gcc

Comment: Okay, may want to note that it is not legal C++ code then and that it will not be portable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for that comment, I added it (with your name) to into the answer.